# Finite Blaschke product and proper maps on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to present tomorrow on an introductory section in several complex variables about proper maps, and they gloss over a fact that seems important to me, but I do not know how to prove it.

> Suppose $f: \Bbb D \to \Bbb D$ is an analytic proper map. Prove that $f$ is a finite [Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product).

That is, prove that $$f(z) = e^{i \theta} \prod_{j=1}^{k} {{z-a_j} \over {1- \overline a_jz}}$$

where, $\theta$ is real, and $a_j \in \Bbb D$.

They mention that to show this, you should consider the fiber of the origin. I'm not sure what to do with this information, though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since $f\colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ is proper, for every $r < 1$, the preimage $f^{-1}(\overline{D_r(0)})$ of the closed disk with radius $r$ is compact, thus contained in $D_\rho(0)$ for some $\rho < 1$. Hence we have

$$\lim_{\lvert z\rvert \to 1} \lvert f(z)\rvert = 1.\tag{1}$$

In particular, $f$ is not constant. So the fibre above the origin, the zero set of $f$ is compact and discrete, hence finite.

Now let $g$ be the product of the Blaschke factors for the zeros of $f$ (according to multiplicity) and consider the function

$$h\colon z \mapsto \frac{f(z)}{g(z)}.$$

Then $h$ is a zero-free holomorphic function on $\mathbb{D}$, and since finite Blaschke products have constant modulus $1$ on the unit circle, we have

$$\lim_{\lvert z\rvert\to 1} \lvert h(z)\rvert = 1.\tag{2}$$

The minimum modulus principle implies that $h$ is a constant of modulus $1$, i.e. $h(z) = e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ok...I knew that fibers were compact, but I have never heard of Blaschke factors, so this function $g$ is new to me.

Comment: Very nice proof!

Comment: The $\frac{z-a_j}{1-\overline{a_j}z}$ are often called Blaschke factors, @JohnnyApple, because they are factors of Blaschke products.

Comment: So, where have we used compactness of the fibers here?

Comment: @JohnnyApple A compact and discrete set is $______$. We need that to deduce the desired representation.

Comment: Ahhhh of course. We needed a finite product. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyApple And we need that the modulus of $g$ is $1$ on the unit circle to deduce that the constant has modulus $1$.

Comment: One more thing... Why is this fiber discrete?

Comment: @JohnnyApple Because the fibres of non-constant holomorphic functions on a domain are discrete. A proper holomorphic map on the unit disk cannot be constant (because ...).

Comment: I don't know. I'm learning basic complex analysis and several variables simultaneously here so I don't know some basic facts like I should.

Comment: If $f\colon \mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{C}$ is constant, say $f(z) \equiv c$, is the fibre $f^{-1}(c)$ compact?

Comment: Oh, of course not. I had forgotten momentarily that the disc is open exclusively. I'm still in topology mode.

Comment: Where are you using the fact that $h$ is zero free?

Comment: @JohnnyApple That implies that we cannot have a $z_0 \in \mathbb{D}$ with $$\lvert h(z_0)\rvert < \min \left\{ \lvert h(\zeta)\rvert : \lvert \zeta\rvert = \rho\right\}$$ for any $\lvert z_0\rvert < \rho < 1$, for otherwise $h$ would have a zero in $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert < \rho\}$, the minimum modulus principle says. And thus we must have $\lvert h(z)\rvert = \lim\limits_{\lvert \zeta\rvert\to 1} \lvert h(\zeta)\rvert = 1$ for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: How does you got limit $ |f(z)|$ is 1 as $ |z|$ goes to 1

Comment: @Sushil Because $f$ is proper. So for every $r < 1$ the preimage $f^{-1}(\{z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant r\})$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: yes this I got. But unable to see from it, how we imply that

Comment: @Sushil Thus $$\rho(r) := \sup \{ \lvert z\rvert : \lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant r\} < 1\,,$$ and that means $\lvert z\rvert > \rho \implies \lvert f(z)\rvert > r$.