Holomorphism on neighborhood of a Disk is a Blaschke Product
This is an old qualifying exam problem:
Let $f$ be holomorphic on a neighborhood of the closed unit disk centered at the origin. Assume that $|f(z)=1|$ if $|z|=1$ and is not a constant on the disk. Assume $|f(z)|=1$ if $|z|=1$ and $f$ is not constant on the disk. Prove there exists a positive integer $k$, points $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_k$ in the open unit disk, positive integers $m_1, \ldots, m_k$ and a complex number $\beta$ with $|\beta|=1$ such that
$$f(z)=\beta \prod_{l=1}^k \bigg(\frac{z-\alpha_l}{1-\overline{\alpha}_lz}\bigg)^{m_k}$$.
I know the following facts:

Blaschke Factors are their own inverses.
Automorphisms of the disk are of the form $e^{i\theta} \psi_{\alpha}$ where $\psi_\alpha$ is the Blaschke factor sending $\alpha$ to $0$.

I don't know what to do about the fact that $f$ is defined on a neighborhood of the disk rather than on the disk. I also don't know that $f$ is an automorphism.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/934070/42969

This should be an easy induction. Base Case: if $f$ has no zeros in the unit disc then $f$ is constant.  Inductive case: $f$ has $m$ zeros in the unit disc so multiply by some $\frac{1}{\psi_\alpha}$ to get a holomorphic function that has $m-1$ zeros in the unit disc and sends the unit circle into itself, then call on the induction hypothesis.
